# connect_login URL for dropbox

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

As per Dropbox REST APIs documentation, the login process has to go through OAUTH Urls like `https://api.dropbox.com/1/oauth/request_token`. But dropbox's iOS SDK makes a call to `https://www.dropbox.com/1/connect_login` which is not documented anywhere. I want to use REST APIs in my application, but I want to display same authentication screen as done by dropbox SDK.

Did anyone face this problem? Does anyone know what dropbox says about using undocumented APIs like `connect_login`?

Answer (score 0):

The latest word from Dropbox on `/connect_login` is:

> That's a special endpoint for the iOS SDK, because of the specific requirements for App Store approval. You should use the official SDKs as provided, and we'll provide updates for these over time.

(taken from https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=104267)